# Unrecognized database format

Tags: microsoft-access

My Microsoft Access 2016 database that I've used for years is suddenly giving me an Unrecognized database format error.  I originally developed the database in Access 2010, but have migrated now to 2016.  I have all of the latest patches.  I have noticed that the Microsoft ADO 3.6 Library is no longer available and so some of my code wouldn't compile.  But I have read there are workarounds for that.  I have tried compact and repair.  Latest, I started building a brand new database and am moving tables and other objects one at a time over.  But the unrecognized database format error pops up again.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you done research on this error? There's several questions about this specific error on our programming sister site: https://www.google.com/search?q=access+upgrade+unrecognized+data+format+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this error on several occasions in the past, using various independent MS Access databases, with the error occurring seemingly at random and not reproducibly as a result of any particular operation.

I've had some success creating a new database file and importing everything from the original database using the *`External Data > New Data Source > From Database > Access`* window and *`Select All`* for each object type tab. However, even if successful, this approach typically only postpones the appearance of the error, which will inevitably return.

In my experience, the only lasting fix is to restore a backup of the database from a time before the error started occurring.

Comment: Thanks for your insight.  It appears to be something wrong in my VB code.  I've noticed that it doesn't compile anymore - like they removed one of the libraries I used before.